# In video media, why use « A », not « À » at the beginning of a sentence?

Tags: prépositions

> **A** part le mien, il devrait en rester quatre.
>
> au lieu de : **À** part le mien, il devrait en rester quatre.

I chalked it up to a mere typo at first, but I now notice that it is quite ubiquitous in video media. I have always wondered why this flagrant grammatical error slips into subtitles, even in the final product.

> **A** vrai dire, ...
>
> au lieu de : **À** vrai dire, ...

Comment: The "À" is especially hard because it's alone, and "A" exists, so it doesn't get corrected. If you start you sentence by "Etonnant", the spell checker will correct it to "Étonnant". When I want to type "À" I have to type "DEJA", then correct it to "DÉJÀ" and remove the extra letters.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat If you have an AZERTY, just press [Alt Gr] + [7/è/`] then your [A] and it will be À.

Comment: Alt + 0192 types À. Too bad Azerty keyboard aren't still adapted to these characters in 2016... I printed a sheet with all the accentuated characters and their Alt codes that I put in front of my computer. Now I know them all by heart but still.

Comment: @Ctouw I guess, it's just not easy to remember (there are a lot of other special characters I use and I have  to remember. Yohann, how do you even do that ? I have no idea how to make that work.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Of cours it's not easy to remember and that's why people get lazy to do it. I'm just one of the few maniacs to learn these codes. As for Yohann V.'s technique, it'll work only on Azerty keyboards. Whatever keyboard you have, find if there is a *`* key, press it and the press Shit + A.

Comment: @Ctouw Ooh ok of course, sure the ` is specifically meant to transform the next character into an accentuated character, like ^ and ¨, I just didn't understand what [7/è/`] meant ^^ And I also remember some codes but it's very random, like I know 155 is "ø" and 157 is "Ø", I just don't  remember the useful ones

Comment: That's why printing a sheet with all the characters is a good idea xD In no time you'll know them all. Actually there are not much you need to know for French, since À and È can be done with ` key. You'll only need to remember Œ (Alt + 0140), œ (Alt + 0156) and É (Alt + 0201).